# extract serialized data from msql database and unserialize and use individual fields in php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a wordpress quiz plugin and I want to extract the questions and answers straight from the database table and use it to create a pdf document. The question is stored as a simple string which is easy to extract but the answers(multiple choice answers) are stored in the database column like this:

```
a:4:{i:0;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option1";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:1;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:1;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option2";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:2;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option3";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:3;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option4";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}}
```

Here the four options are 'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3' and 'Option4'. How do I extract them as the four strings, or as a string array?

EDIT------------------------------------

As suggested I used the unserialize function as follows:

```
$ser ='a:4:{i:0;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option1";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:1;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:1;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option2";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:2;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option3";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:3;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option4";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}}';

$un = unserialize($ser);
if(!is_array($un)){
    echo $un;
}else{
    foreach($un as $value){
    echo $value."\n";
    }
}
```

I got the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 63 of 822 bytes in <path> on line 5
```

How do I tackle this?

EDIT2---------------------------

Using str_replace() the code worked when I set the variable $ser myself copying the value from the mysql table.
Now when I extract it through php code, the variable $ser is no longer a string. I cannot typecast it to string. So str_replace() doesn't work. So I tried regular expression function preg_replace(), but it cannot replace '*_' taken together. So I replaced just '*'.
Here is the code:

```
$host="<>"; // Host name 
$username="<>"; // Mysql username 
$password="<>"; // Mysql password 

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("<>")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql="<the query>";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);


    $ser = $row['answer_data'];
    echo $ser.'<br/><br/>';

    $pattern = '/\*/';
    $replace = '_00';
    $ser = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $ser);
    echo $ser.'<br/><br/>';


    $un = unserialize($ser);
    $un = json_decode(json_encode($un));
    foreach($un as $obj){
        echo $obj->_00_answer;
    }



    mysql_close();
```

Here's the output:

```
a:4:{i:0;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option1";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:1;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:1;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option2";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:2;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option3";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}i:3;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:7:"Option4";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}}

a:4:{i:0;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"_00_answer";s:7:"Option1";s:8:"_00_html";b:0;s:10:"_00_points";i:1;s:11:"_00_correct";b:1;s:14:"_00_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"_00_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"_00_mapper";N;}i:1;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"_00_answer";s:7:"Option2";s:8:"_00_html";b:0;s:10:"_00_points";i:1;s:11:"_00_correct";b:0;s:14:"_00_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"_00_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"_00_mapper";N;}i:2;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"_00_answer";s:7:"Option3";s:8:"_00_html";b:0;s:10:"_00_points";i:1;s:11:"_00_correct";b:0;s:14:"_00_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"_00_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"_00_mapper";N;}i:3;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"_00_answer";s:7:"Option4";s:8:"_00_html";b:0;s:10:"_00_points";i:1;s:11:"_00_correct";b:0;s:14:"_00_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"_00_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"_00_mapper";N;}}
```

And here is the log file record:

```
[11-Aug-2016 04:01:42 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 63 of 934 bytes in <path> on line 24
[11-Aug-2016 04:01:42 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <path> on line 26
```

EDIT3-------------------

output of `echo json_encode($ser);` while extracting from database:

```
"a:4:{i:0;O:27:\"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes\":7:{s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_answer\";s:7:\"Option1\";s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000_html\";b:0;s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_points\";i:1;s:11:\"\u0000*\u0000_correct\";b:1;s:14:\"\u0000*\u0000_sortString\";s:0:\"\";s:18:\"\u0000*\u0000_sortStringHtml\";b:0;s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_mapper\";N;}i:1;O:27:\"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes\":7:{s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_answer\";s:7:\"Option2\";s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000_html\";b:0;s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_points\";i:1;s:11:\"\u0000*\u0000_correct\";b:0;s:14:\"\u0000*\u0000_sortString\";s:0:\"\";s:18:\"\u0000*\u0000_sortStringHtml\";b:0;s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_mapper\";N;}i:2;O:27:\"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes\":7:{s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_answer\";s:7:\"Option3\";s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000_html\";b:0;s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_points\";i:1;s:11:\"\u0000*\u0000_correct\";b:0;s:14:\"\u0000*\u0000_sortString\";s:0:\"\";s:18:\"\u0000*\u0000_sortStringHtml\";b:0;s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_mapper\";N;}i:3;O:27:\"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes\":7:{s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_answer\";s:7:\"Option4\";s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000_html\";b:0;s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_points\";i:1;s:11:\"\u0000*\u0000_correct\";b:0;s:14:\"\u0000*\u0000_sortString\";s:0:\"\";s:18:\"\u0000*\u0000_sortStringHtml\";b:0;s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000_mapper\";N;}}"
```

output of `echo json_encode($ser);` previously, i.e. copy-pasting the value from phpmyadmin:

```
"a:4:{i:0;O:27:\"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes\":7:{s:10:\"*_answer\";s:7:\"Option1\";s:8:\"*_html\";b:0;s:10:\"*_points\";i:1;s:11:\"*_correct\";b:1;s:14:\"*_sortString\";s:0:\"\";s:18:\"*_sortStringHtml\";b:0;s:10:\"*_mapper\";N;}i:1;O:27:\"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes\":7:{s:10:\"*_answer\";s:7:\"Option2\";s:8:\"*_html\";b:0;s:10:\"*_points\";i:1;s:11:\"*_correct\";b:0;s:14:\"*_sortString\";s:0:\"\";s:18:\"*_sortStringHtml\";b:0;s:10:\"*_mapper\";N;}i:2;O:27:\"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes\":7:{s:10:\"*_answer\";s:7:\"Option3\";s:8:\"*_html\";b:0;s:10:\"*_points\";i:1;s:11:\"*_correct\";b:0;s:14:\"*_sortString\";s:0:\"\";s:18:\"*_sortStringHtml\";b:0;s:10:\"*_mapper\";N;}i:3;O:27:\"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes\":7:{s:10:\"*_answer\";s:7:\"Option4\";s:8:\"*_html\";b:0;s:10:\"*_points\";i:1;s:11:\"*_correct\";b:0;s:14:\"*_sortString\";s:0:\"\";s:18:\"*_sortStringHtml\";b:0;s:10:\"*_mapper\";N;}}"
```

So there are indeed extra characters now. The collation in database is 'utf8_general_c'

Comment: That's a serialized string - http://php.net/serialize and http://php.net/unserialize (which is what you want)

Comment: Thanks. let me check

Comment: I tried the unserialize function. Please see the edit in the question. Thanks

Comment: Your best bet here is to take a look at the source code of the plugin in question. There's certain to be code to unserialize this data.  It looks like it contains a serialized object of class `WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes`. You might also contact the plugin author and ask for help.

Comment: There is an error in the serialised string: it has `s:10:"*_answer"` at a certain point, which means *"here comes a string of 10 characters: `*_answer` "*. But as you can see, it is not a string of 10 characters, but of only 8. So that is why you get the error. You'll have to fix the code that produced that inconsistent string.

Comment: I have put up a question there too, but they have not responded yet. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to a specific WordPress plugin that likely the plugin's author should address

Comment: What if I change the question to be specifically about unserializing data extracted from a database? As you can see from my second edit, it is not restricted to a single plugin but about general msql and php.

Comment: Stop using the loooooong deprecated *mysql_* functions. They are not maintained, and don't even exist in the latest versions of PHP. Use *mysqli_* functions instead, or even better: *PDO*.

Comment: Please also replace your `echo` statements by `echo json_encode($ser) . '<br><br>';`, so with `json_encode`, otherwise we might be missing "invisible" characters in the output. Then provide *that* output in your question.

Comment: Now I am using mysqli_ functions, but still the same problem persists. Using var_dump I saw the variable is a string, still the str_replace() function doesn't work with \*_ (it can replace alphabets). The output with json_encode is provided in the question as EDIT3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialised string has null bytes in many of the property names. These don't display when you `echo` them. You'll see for instance this:

```
*_answer
```

...while in fact the original string (not echo-ed) has this (where `<NUL>` represents a null byte):

```
<NUL>*<NUL>_answer
```

These null bytes indicate that these properties are protected, as stated in the [PHP documentation on `serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php):

> [...] protected members have a '*' prepended to the member name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

If you just take the echo-ed string, and then try to `unserialize` that, you'll get the errors you mention, since the indicated string length (like `s:10:`) will no longer correspond to the length of the null-byte-stripped property name that follows.

If on the other hand you `unserialize` the original string, it will produce the array, but then the elements will have protected properties, which makes it hard to access them.

Here is code that will replace the null-asterisk-null sequences with three other, readable characters (I chose: "key"), keeping the length unchanged. That way, the  `unserialize` function will not produce protected properties, and you can easily access them with names like "key_answer":

```
// Replace two NUL bytes separated by an asterisk with three other characters: "key"
// Note that you need to use double quotes for the first argument.
// This will make it easier to access those properties:
$ser = str_replace("\0*\0_", 'key_', $ser);
// Now unserialize this:
$un = unserialize($ser);
// Avoid warnings about incomplete objects: 
// turn specific class objects to standard associative arrays:
$un = json_decode(json_encode($un), true);
// Extract the answers:
$answers = array_column($un, 'key_answer');
// Output the answers (but you could also use a foreach loop):
echo implode(",", $answers);
```

If your version of PHP is older than 5.5, then it does not support `array_column`. Instead just write:

```
foreach($un as $row) {
    $answers[] = $row['key_answer'];
}
```

Comment: Now that I am extracting this serialized data from the database and storing it in a variable, the variable is no longer string type. So the str_replace() doesn't work. I cannot cast it to string type. So I tried using regular expression, preg_replace(). But it too cannot replace '\*_' , i.e. underscores preceded by any character. I had to replace '\*' with '_00' and then it throws a notice and a warning and doesn't execute. The code is in the 'EDIT2' section of my question.

Comment: See my comment under your question. Also, if it is not *string* type, then what is it? This you can see by doing a `var_dump`. Honestly, I think it is *string*, type, but the character encoding is different. Which character encoding is your database using? I repeat you should *not* use *mysql_* functions: they are not maintained since many years. You should not use them.

Comment: I tried using a try catch block in the str_replace() function, but even that doesn't throw any exceptions and the characters are not changed.

Comment: I rewrote my answer given the fact that the original string contains null bytes (as shown in the JSON encoded output in your last edit).

Comment: Now when I use `$answers = array_column($un, 'key_answer');` an error is thrown `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function array_column() in <path> on line 22` and when I use the foreach loop like before, an error is thrown `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in <path> on line 26`

Comment: Which PHP version are you running?

Comment: This problem is solved by accessing this unserialised output as an associative array as follows: `foreach($un as $obj){
  echo $obj[key_answer];
 }`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Updated my answer. You are apparently on PHP < 5.5

Comment: my php version is 5.4.45